# Update links using a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I want to update several links based on the content of a textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myvar = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
</script>

<input type="text" value="ghostbusters" id="textbox">
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=' + myvar">YouTube</a>
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.imdb.com/find?s=all&q=' + myvar">IMDb</a>
```

No matter what I do it seems to set the `var` to `undefined` :(

If I set `var myvar = 'some text';` it works fine, and the `var` gets added to the url.

If I debug it using an alertbox it shows the content of the textbox just fine.

I'm a bit new to JavaScript, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this everything? You also need an event like a button click or loss of focus on the textbox that tells you when text has been entered into the box.

Comment: Ofcause I would like it to update if I enter another text than "ghostbusters"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in any way knowledgeable about JS & HTML, but my guess is you need to reverse the order of the script block and input. By the time the script is executed, the element doesn't exist yet because it's declared afterwards. Also, myvar will take the value of whatever you've got in the text box when the page loads, probably not what you're after.

To have dynamically generate URLs, only store a reference to the input in myvar and use myvar.value during concatenation.

Cheers,

Marius

Answer (score 0):

It's because when `myvar` is assigned, the DOM isn't ready, therefore you need to wrap the assignment of `myvar` in an `addEventListener` otherwise it cannot get the value of the input field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myvar;

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function DOMContentLoaded() {
        myvar = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    });

</script>

<input type="text" value="ghostbusters" id="textbox">
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=' + myvar">YouTube</a>
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.imdb.com/find?s=all&q=' + myvar">IMDb</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function DOMContentLoaded() {
   var myele = document.getElementById("textbox");
});
</script>

<input type="text" value="ghostbusters" id="textbox">
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=' + myele.value">YouTube</a>
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.imdb.com/find?s=all&q=' + myele.value">IMDb</a>
```

document.getElementById("textbox").value return a static string. Value of `myvar` would not change even if you change the value of #textbox element.